# Avoid postback on button click

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, postback

I have a Search feature. if the search string is empty and user clicks "GO" then the postback of the gridview shouldn't happen and the alert (as mentioned in below code) should get fired up.

My gridview is in update panel. Below is the logic that i have written but it doesn't works.

```
 protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!txtSearchString.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                BinGrid();
                upnl1.update //update panel is updated here.
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.upnl1, this.GetType(), "Search", "alert('Enter search text');", false);
                //upnlgvOpportinities.Update();
                //upnlAdmin.Update();
                return;
            }
        }
```

Please help! Let me know if any info is needed

Comment: How can i register the JS from code side?

Comment: The alert box comes succesfully but the postback still happens!

Comment: do you put your button inside update panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace Your ScriptManager line with below code line.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.upnl1, this.GetType(), "Script", "alert('Enter search text');", true);
```

Comment: No it is not inside update panel. I guess now i need to remove the first argument

Comment: Please, Place you button inside update panel. and then check it again.it will work.

Answer (score 4):

This logic is wrong. It should do using javascript if you want to avoid the postback at first place.

Have your javascript return `false` when textbox is empty and `true` when not

`<asp:button runat="server".... OnClientClick="return myfunction(); " />`

You can check if textbox is empty or not in `myfunction()`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a request to the server to be sent (if I understood your needs right), than you need a client-side solution, that is handle button click with javascript and conditionally prevent the postback. However your current code is server-side, and is executed on a server **after** the postback has occurred.

As to client-side, here is one possible way. Define a js function that simply checks the value of the search box and returns `false` if it is empty. On the button click simply call this function. If a click handler returns `false`, further processing of the button click will be stopped and the postback won't occur:

```
function checkSearch() {
    var searchBox = document.getElementById('HereComesSearchBoxClientID');

    if (searchBox.value == '') {
        alert('Enter search text');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

<asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="GO" OnClick="ServerSideHandler" OnClientClick="checkSearch();" />
```

Comment: +1: please pass `this` so that you dont have to worry about client id

Answer (score 0):

@Madhur Ahuja's way is the correct one. Expanding that a little bit more.

HTML

```
<asp:Button ID="txtSearchString" runat="server" 
        OnClientClick="javascript:return CheckifEmpty(this);" />
```

Javascript

```
function CheckifEmpty(objSearchBox) {
    //always trim, otherwise it will accept a string of spaces
    var isEmpty = objSearchBox.value.trim() == "";
    if (isEmpty) {
        alert('Enter search text');
    }
    return !isEmpty;
}
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim = function() {
        return this.replace(/^\s*(\S*(?:\s+\S+)*)\s*$/, "$1");
    };
}
```